# Can I Rename DataTable in QTP from 'Default.xls' to something else?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

Can I Rename DataTable in QTP from 'Default.xls' to something else?If not then why and if yes than how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach other xls by clicking in

`File->Settings->Resources->Data Table-> Other Location`

I guess you can't change default xls file name without setting this option

[image: Data Table option]

Edit: You can try to edit .usr file for test, there is a section with files used in test [ExtraFiles]

Comment: Can You please elaborate how to edit .usr file for datatable name changing?

Comment: Just open it by notepad++ for instance. The last paragraph of file is defined as [ExtraFiles]. .Usr file is in root directory of test. It's not recommended , but if you really want to change default.xls name without using option mentioned in my previous post - this could work(but i'm not sure! it's just my suppositions). Remember to make a backup of your test ;)

Comment: Your previous post helped.I changed the name inside .usr file but it does effected my testcase.Thanks :)